# image blurry detection with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, ionic-framework, blurry

I need to check if an image is blurry using JavaScript. This is for an Ionic project, and I want to reject blurred images. I cannot find a way to do this. Can someone help me please?

I've find one way, but I think it only works if is done within a NodeJS server: https://github.com/timotgl/inspector-bokeh

I need a way to do it on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Your referenced repo [inspector-bokeh](https://github.com/timotgl/inspector-bokeh) can be used in client side, which supports UMD. And you can check the [demo.html](https://github.com/timotgl/inspector-bokeh/blob/master/demo.html) for a client side usage example.

Comment: what is UMD exactly?

Comment: Check this [article](https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/). If you're not familiar with js module knowledge, you can directly refer like `window.measureBlur`.

Comment: oki! now it's clear, thanks! and yesterday tried the inspector bokeh, and works perfectly to "blur" images, but the problem is.. I want to blur camara problems (focus and move while you do the photo) and no works for this, but ok for your help! is very cool, thanks!